# Servicenow REST-API returns 200 Ok in case of business logic errors

Tags: servicenow

I'm using servicenow rest-api to update sys_user table entry. I have a column constraint on Home Phone field, it is mandatory. But when send a request for update which makes Home Phone empty, servicenow accepts this request and updates a user and returns 200 OK response. 
I also tried to use Business rules to add this validation and throw an exception in script, but service now ignores it.

I want service now to return an error in response in such cases. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an import set and the import API instead of the table API.  By using an import set you can easily control imports via several methods:

- You could enforce mandatory fields by setting a field mandatory on a table via the dictionary and if the enforce mandatory fields box is checked on the import set it will reject (but this might not stop null entries)
- If nulls are slipping in you can use a transform map to make certain fields required (required for the import set but they may not be mandatory on the target table) and then you can apply a script to a field to manipulate it or reject based on its content using functions like JSUtil.notNil(source.home_phone).

  - You can also apply onBefore Transform scripts.  Ex: This will cause the API to respond with a custom error message

    `// if home phone is not null, undefined, Nan, empty string (""), 0 or false this evalutes to true.

    if (source.home_phone) {
    error = false;
    } else{
    error_message = "Home Phone is a required field";
    error = true;"
    }`